# How can I show the max number

Tags: prolog

I know my question will sound silly for you. It's just I can't get this language since it's very different from the languages I know. I need to take the max number of the rating predict but I didn't know how to do it. Whenever I do researches, what appears is lists while the rating isn't a list. Here is my code:

```
movie(name(thedarknight),director(christopher),
         [starring(magijelnar,10000),starring(aroneikhart,30000)],
         rating(9)).
movie(name(shazam),director(david),
         [starring(markstrong,1000),starring(jackdaniel,3000)],
         rating(7)).
```

& something else, am I doing the matrix right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This predicate will obtain the name of the movie and its rating from the structure:

```
movierating(Name, Rating) :-
    movie(name(Name), _, _, rating(Rating)).
```

If you want to get the maximum rating, the most straightforward and least efficient way to do it is to say, I have obtained rating X and there is no rating Y that is greater than X. Thus X is the maximum. In code, this looks like this:

```
highest_rating(Rating) :-
    movie(_, _, _, rating(Rating)),
    \+ (movie(_, _, _, rating(OtherRating)), 
        OtherRating > Rating).
```

Probably you will want to know the name of the movie too, so you can just add that into your initial query:

```
highest_rated(Movie, Rating) :-
    movie(name(Movie), _, _, rating(Rating)),
    \+ (movie(_, _, _, rating(OtherRating)), 
        OtherRating > Rating).
```

This is going to be O(N^2), which might be too inefficient for your liking, in which case you should probably use `findall/3` to get all the ratings and then ask for the maximum. That would look like this:

```
?- findall(Rating, movie(_, _, _, rating(Rating)), Ratings), 
   max_list(Ratings, Rating).
Rating = 9,
Ratings = [9, 7].
```

This is also possible with library(aggregate):

```
?- aggregate(max(Rating, Movie), 
      Movie^D^A^movie(name(Movie), D, A, rating(Rating)), 
      max(Rating, Movie)).
Rating = 9,
Movie = thedarknight.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me, it's just not like this. I mean I want to get the max rate of the two structures. The first rate is 9 and the second is 7, so the query should show the 9 as a maximum if u understand what I mean 

Comment: @RanaMohammad I have edited my answer so hopefully now it answers your actual question :)

Comment: Yeah! The findall works thaaanks  the only problem is that I don't want to write it while running the program. The first solution you proposed, when I tried it, it gave me the whole list without specifying any max number. Could u please tell me what the problem is? Sorry for bothering 

Comment: I tried to write the code of findall in the editor, and it works!! I got one problem, it doesn't return the name of the movie. I tried multiple things but none of them worked 

Comment: I DID IT! It works perfectly now ! Thaaanks a lot! U were such a great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

library([solution_sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)) has been recently introduced in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- order_by([desc(X)],movie(name(N),_,_,rating(X))).
X = 9,
N = thedarknight ;
X = 7,
N = shazam.
```

Comment: Very cool library! Thanks for posting! I think the complete solution is actually more like `limit(1, order_by([desc(Rating)], movie(name(Name), _, _, rating(Rating)))).` though.